# when should we use packsize to specify the struct layout?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

Sometimes I think we can specify pack size to specify the layout of the struct. I am wondring if there is any case we must specify pack size?

Answer (score 3):

When you need the memory layout to match exactly a binary format defined elsewhere, eg. file formats or network protocols.

Answer (score 1):

Generally this should be avoided.  The edge cases where it is appropriate is when using the structures to communicate between machines of various architectures (as in data passed over a network for instance).  However even in that case, you have to be aware of all the architecture that you are supporting having any alignment issues (for instance, if it only allows access on a quadword boundary for instance).

Answer (score 0):

The only time I used it was when I had a VB program call a C++ DLL.  The structures HAD to match or didn't work.

Comment: what you did when you call from c++ from VB? you need to specify packsize to what?

Comment: I packed them so there was no padding in the structures...then they matched.  I also found out, painfully, that a VB int was a different size than a C++ int (at the time). The sizes of the items in the struct must also match.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about `#pragma pack`, that is used to specify [data alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment).  If you want to get the size of a structure (e.g. for memory allocation), use the `sizeof` operator.

```
structSize = sizeof( myStructType );
```